# JVM version manager

Tags: java, jvm, rvm

Is there [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) equivalent for the Java world?

I'm looking for tool which allow me to easily download and install a new JVMs and switch between them. For example:

```
jvm install <version>
jvm list //will list installed JVMs on my system
jvm use jdk1.6 //will switch my env to jdk 1.6 version, etc.
```

Comment: As jocull had suggested, I find sdkman the best java version manager for my purposes https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu you can specify which JVM you want to use via command (works only for JVM installed from apt-get or aptitude)

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Or by setting JAVA_HOME. Here is good tutorial:

http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonlinux.html

Comment: yeah.. but maven depends on JAVA_HOME.. so you have to do both

Answer (score 41):

http://www.jenv.be/ will allow this type of control.

Comment: This doesn't seem to support Windows, or does it?

Comment: same for sdkman, both are only supported using wsl, cygwin etc. so no native windows support!

Comment: For completeness, jenv does not satisfy the request to easily install JVMs.

Answer (score 37):

[SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) is a similar tool for the Java ecosystem. Supports various Java versions, Scala, Clojure, Kotlin, Groovy, and build tools like Maven and Gradle.

Works on Mac and Linux, with some mentions of support for Windows depending on how hard you are willing to try :)

Answer (score 15):

As it is not (yet) in the list of possibilities, there's also [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/).
[asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) does not only provide version management for java, it has plugins for [~400 different languages and tools](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-plugins) by default. You can find more plugins on [github](https://github.com/topics/asdf-plugin) by the topic, or [create your own](https://asdf-vm.com/plugins/create.html).

Here is an example how to setup a new install (you can also install [completion](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf) so you don't have to list the versions first). The java plugin is added, a specific version (there are versions for `adoptopenjdk`, `corretto`, `dragonwell`, `graalvm`, `liberica`, `mandrel`, `microsoft`, `openjdk`, `oracle`, `sapmachine`, `semeru`, `temurin`, `trava`, `zulu`) is installed and configured to be the global (or local version) to use:

```bash
asdf plugin-add java                # Add java Plugin
asdf list-all java                  # List all available java versions
asdf install java temurin-20.0.1+9  # Install specific jdk version
asdf install java temurin-17.0.7+7  # Install another jdk version
asdf global java temurin-17.0.7+7   # Set the global jdk version
asdf local java temurin-20.0.1+9    # Set the local version for calls from the current directory
```

[asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) uses a file in `$HOME/.tool-versions` to configure the global selected version. If you call any tool in a directory that has a `.tool-versions` file with a different version, that one is used (defined with `asdf local …`).

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness, there are two more - [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) (of which I am the author; written in Go and designed after nvm/gvm/rvm)
and [jenv](https://github.com/linux-china/jenv) (not to confuse with jenv.be; doesn't support installation from oracle but can install from a custom zip).

Comment: I prefer the jenv.be due to the simplicity(installation of jdk should be package manager, not version manager). but it only supports Unix-like system.

Comment: The first option seems to be abandoned.

Comment: The second option seems to be abandoned too.

Answer (score 6):

With JVMs, if you need to switch between them you just need to use a batch file (or powershell script)  to manage the classpath and JVM path.    You don't need to rely on the system default JVM path and instead just allow your app to point to whatever JVM you like by changing classpath and JVM path environment in the shell that runs the JVM.

For programs that are getting Java location from the Registry, in theory you could use a batch script to update that also.

In this respect Java is way easier than "Ruby version manager".

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use update-java-alternatives (from the java-common package).   The update-alternatives command will not update every one of the symbolic links for various java /bin executables, which is why update-java-alternatives is better.

So to go for OpenJDK 6 to 7, use `update-java-alternatives -l` to get a list of Java alternatives and then used `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` to switch the JDK.

CAVEAT: The command above might throw the following errors,

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so.
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: 
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

This is because the openjdk plugin is not installed by default. To fix run `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin` and rerun update-java-alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JVMS [here](https://github.com/ystyle/jvms) it is very easy to use and the only one I could find for Windows, it works like RVM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).