# Is there any Java version manager?

Tags: java, linux, shell, build, rvm

I used to have multiple `JDK` installed on my `Linux` machine, and I like to switch from one version to another from the command-line ( I used to change my `JAVA_HOME` manually):

This is my current approach  :

I `source` a `~/.paths` in my `.bashrc`.

the `.paths` contain all the `JDK` installed on my machine.

```
JDK7="~/local/jdk1.7.0_15"
JDK8="~/local/jdk1.8.0"
// I use Jdk 7 by default 
JDK_HOME=$JDK7;     
// including $JDK_HOME/bin to the $PATH
```

When I want t switch to `JDK8`, I modify the `JDK_HOME` variable to point on `JDK8` in the file, and I `re-source` my `.paths` file.

I know that `IDE` can manage multiple `JDK` easily, but I want an [rvm](https://rvm.io/) like solution.

- Is there any better trick  ?
- Better more, Is there any equivalent for [rvm](https://rvm.io/) in Java ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JVM version manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463936/jvm-version-manager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [jdk_switcher](https://github.com/michaelklishin/jdk_switcher) although it is quite static to some `ubuntu` paths - it should be easy to modify it to run from other paths.

There is a plan to make `RVM 2` support switching more then just `Ruby` versions, you can read more about it  [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xW9GeEpLOWPcddDg_hOPvK4oeLxJmU3Q5FiCNT7nTAc/edit?usp=sharing).

anyone with the link can comment.

Comment: the `RVM2` plan looks promising, thanks @mpapis for the mention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such solution.
See this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239739/rvm-like-tool-for-java) to a solution with symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Now , I'm using [jdk-manager](https://github.com/tarrsalah/jdk-manager), a little bash script to manage multiple `JDKS` installations.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many Java versions installed as you want to. Just install to a folder of your choosing and use some convention.

If you want to make one-time use of a particular version run it with a full path (for example):

```
>C:\java\jdk-6u35\bin\java.exe
```

or

```
>/java/jdk-6u35/bin/java.exe
```

If you want to change to just use it, change your path to put the version you want at the front. The path might be similar to that shown above.

Be sure to change JAVA_HOME as well and any other environment settings that include a reference to the java location.

Note that some tools have internal configuration as to which java version to use. Eclipse is a good example. You have to set up a list of your JVMs and then select one for each project or for all projects.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own script to manage java versions.  I use some sites that require Oracle Java and usually the latest version, so I can't use apt/aptitude and therefore can't use update-alternatives or jdk-manager (which uses update-alternatives).

Here's my script.  I don't develop professionally, so it's probably a mess, but it serves my purposes.  It only considers java versions stored in /usr/lib/jvm.

```
#!/bin/bash

# the proper way....
# + update: update-alternatives only works for versions installed by apt or aptitude
# ... same for jdk-manager (uses update-alternatives to do the heavy lifting)
#echo "The proper way is:"
#echo "$ update-alternatives --config java"

#exit

# the rest is (no longer) depreciated....

echo "The current default java is $(readlink --canonicalize `which java`)"

PS3='Select Java to install: '
options=( $(find /usr/lib/jvm -iname java) )
noptions=${#options[@]}
(( loption=noptions-1 ))
options[${#options[@]}]="Quit"

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
  for i in $(seq 0 $loption); do
     [ "$opt" == "${options[$i]}" ] && \
        javapath=${options[$i]}
  done
  if [ "$javapath" ]; then
    break
  fi
  if [ "$opt" == "Quit" ]; then
        echo "Nothing installed."; 
        exit
  else 
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";
        continue
  fi
done


# remove the old link (might be superfluous)
#rm -vf -- "$link"

# set new link (symbolic, force, verbose)
sudo ln -sTfv "$javapath" "/usr/bin/java"

default_java_dir=$(echo "$javapath" | grep --only-matching --regexp="\/usr\/lib\/jvm\/[^\/]*")
sudo ln -sTfv "$default_java_dir" "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"

java_bin_dir=$(echo "$javapath" | sed 's/[^\/]*$//')
echo $java_bin_dir
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javac" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javac"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javadoc" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javadoc"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javafxpackager" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javafxpackager"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javah" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javah"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javap" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javap"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}java-rmi.cgi" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}java-rmi.cgi"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}java_vm" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}java_vm"
[ -f "${java_bin_dir}javaws" ] && sudo ln -sfv -t "/usr/bin" "${java_bin_dir}javaws"

find_dir=$(dirname "$java_bin_dir")
pluginpath=$(find "$find_dir" -name libnpjp2.so)

#exit

echo -n "Install $pluginpath as the Java plugin? [y/N]: "
read
response=$(echo $REPLY | sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/')

if [ "${response:0:1}" == "Y" ]; then

  # directories for plugins

  plugin_dirs="/usr/lib/firefox/plugins
                     /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
                     /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
                     /opt/google/chrome
                     /home/james/.mozilla/plugins"


  # first, clean out anything we might have improperly installed already
  echo "Using 'sudo' to remove any installed java plugins..."

  for pdir in $plugin_dirs; do
     sudo rm --verbose --force "$pdir/libjavaplugin_oji.so" "$pdir/libnpjp2.so" "$pdir/IcedTeaPlugin.so"
  done

  # okay, trying brute force and awkwardness....
  echo "Using 'sudo' to install \"$pluginpath\" in several places..."

  for pdir in $plugin_dirs; do
     sudo ln --symbolic --verbose --force "$pluginpath" "$pdir"
  done
fi

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Debian or a derived GNU/Linux distribution, you can use update alternatives to set what is currently being run when you type java.

Try typing

```
    update-alternatives --display java
```

That will show you what alternatives you have available.
This command is non-destructive, that is, it doesn't change anything.

```
    man update-alternatives
```

Will give you the manual for the tool.
The command you will likely want though is:

```
    update-alternatives --config java
```

Which will give you a simple, interactive way of setting the java program. You can also use --set if you want to script it.

Of course, you should not trust me without running man first, because people sometimes go on the Internet and tell lies. ;)

EDIT: I forgot, [this link](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2002/08/msg02808.html) introduces update-alternatives in a good (if Vi specific) way.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, you can use update-alternatives to not only set paths to java, javac, and other binaries but also your JAVA_HOME. Since all it does is manage links, you can install a link to your jdk directories and then set JAVA_HOME to point to that link. For example, "update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/jdk jdk /path/to/jdk8 1" will install a link to your jdk directory. You then add "export JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jdk" in .bashrc, .profile, or whatever file you use to set environment variables and any alternative you install under the name jdk will be pointed to by JAVA_HOME when you switch with update-alternatives --config jdk. If you are using alternatives already for the java executables, you can use --slave to make jdk whenever java does.